# Using pyedflib to write csv to EDF+

Tags: python, csv, python-import, european-data-format

Wanted to know is it possible to just directly read in data from csv file and print everything into a EDF file using PYEDFLIB? The biggest challenge is that PYEDFLIB code on their website doesnt support large Data

Link for reference about pyedflib 
http://pyedflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: were u able to do this??